# Invalid Syntax. No area highlighted

Tags: python

In here somewhere. P.S. Its a cricket game. Nowhere in the code is highlighted. What can I do? Thanks in advance for answering. I need this for an assignment. It worked fin untill I edited the area where it displays the runs scored by the player. I was going to add how many wickets had fallen, but somwhere in this time frame I messed up. Thanks

```
                     playruns = playtemp
                     playscore = playscore + playruns
                     print("You scored" ,playruns, "runs.", team, "is on", playscore," runs.")
                     elif playruns == 5:
                            print("Your player is out! ", team,"'s current score is:", playscore,"runs")
                            playouts = playouts + 1
                     if playouts == 5:
                            print("You are all out. Now it is your turn to bowl.")
                            while compouts != 5:




                                          print("The Androidz scored", compruns,"runs. The total score of the Androidz is", compscore,"runs.")
                                          compruns = 0
                                          comptemp = 0
                                          compouts = compouts + 1
                                   if compouts == 5:
                                          print("Game over man, game over.")
                                          print("Your score was:", playscore,)
                                          print("The Androidz score was:", compscore.)
                                          if playscore > compscore:
                                                 playagain = input("You are the winner. 


                            print("The Androidz scored", compruns,"runs. The total score of the Androidz is", compscore.)
                            compruns = 0
                            comptemp = 0
                            compouts = compouts + 1
                     if compouts == 5:
                            print("The Androidz are all out. Congratulations.")
                            while playouts != 5:
                                   print("You are now batting.")
                                   playmindset = input("For this ball would you like to play agressively 'a', or defensively 'd'")
                                   if playmindset == "a":
                                         playtemp = random.choice([1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,])
                                   elif playmindset == "d":
                                          playtemp = random.choice([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,])
                                   playruns = playtemp
                                   playscore = playscore + playruns
                                   if playruns != 5:
                                          print("You scored" ,playruns, "runs.", team, "is on", playscore,"runs")
                                   elif playruns == 5:
                                          print("Your player is out! ", team,"'s current score is:", playscore.)
                                          playouts = playouts + 1
                                   if playouts == 5:
                                          print("Game over man, game over.")
                                          print("Your score was:", playscore,)
                                          print("The Androidz score was:", compscore,)
                                          if playscore > compscore:
                                                 playagain = input("You are the winner. Play againg?. 'y' for yes, 'n' for no.")
                                          elif playscore < compscore:
                                                 playagain = input("You are the loser. Play againg?. 'y' for yes, 'n' for no.")

elif coinguess != headsortails:
       while compouts != 5:
              print("You lost the toss. You are bowling.")
              print("The Androidz are at the crease. The hot sun beams down upon the ground.\nVictory is a must for", team, "if" , captainname, "wishes to remain as captain.")
              bowltodo = input("Would you like to bowl or forfeit?")
              comptemp = random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,])
              if bowltodo == "bowl":
                     compruns = comptemp
                     compscore = compruns + compscore
                     print("The Androidz scored", compruns,"runs. The total score of the Androidz is",compscore,"runs.")
                     compruns = 0
                     comptemp = 0
                     compouts = compouts + 1
              if compouts == 5:
                     print("The Androidz are all out. Congratulations.")
                     while playouts != 5:
                            print("You are now batting.")
                            playmindset = input("For this ball would you like to play agressively 'a', or defensively 'd'")
                            if playmindset == "a":
                                   playtemp = random.choice([1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,])
                            elif playmindset == "d":
                                   playtemp = random.choice([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,])
                            playruns = playtemp
                            playscore = playscore + playruns
                            if playruns != 5:
                                   print("You scored" ,playruns, "runs.", team, "is on", playscore.)
                            elif playruns == 5:
                                   print("Your player is out! ", team,"'s current score is:", playscore.)
                                   playouts = playouts + 1
                            if playouts == 5:
                                   print("Game over man, game over.")
                                   print("Your score was:", playscore,)
                                   print("The Androidz score was:",compscore,)
                                   if playscore > compscore:
                                          playagain = input("You are the winner. Play againg?. 'y' for yes, 'n' for no.")
                                   elif playscore < compscore:
                                          playagain = input("You are the loser. Play againg?. 'y' for yes, 'n' for no.")
```

Comment: You could use comments to make your code easier to understand.

Comment: yeah sorry, I should get into the habit of using comments. Thanks for remining me.

Comment: Please reduce this down to a [minimal example](http://sscce.org). You may fix the problem by refactoring into short, self-contained functions; if not, you can then just post the one that doesn't work. This will also have the benefit of reducing duplicated code and making it easier to follow.

Comment: You have an `elif` with no `if`. Line 33 of that code block. (`elif playruns == 5:`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several syntax errors. The first one is here on line 33

```
elif playmindset == "d":
    playtemp = random.choice([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,])
playruns = playtemp
playscore = playscore + playruns
print("You scored" ,playruns, "runs.", team, "is on", playscore," runs.")
elif playruns == 5: # this line
    print("Your player is out! ", team,"'s current score is:", playscore,"runs")
    playouts = playouts + 1
```

That second `elif` raises a syntax error because there is no `if`  that precedes it. Perhaps you meant to place the 3 lines in between the 2 `elif`s in the first one, or maybe make the second `elif` a new `if`. That is for you to fix.

Furhermore syntax errors are raised because you print stuff like this at several places in your program (lines 52, 66, 84, 120, 122)

```
print("The Androidz score was:", compscore.)
```

the `.` behind `compscore` insinuates you are going to call a function on it, or a property or something. Because you do not do that it raises a syntax error. I think you just want to print a dot at the end of the line, in that case just change them to

```
print("The Androidz score was:", compscore + ".")
```

Comment: Or `"The Androidz score was: {0}.".format(compscore)`